# Why can't I modify a construction environment from within a pseudo builder (AddMethod)?

Tags: scons

I need to modify a set of variables in multiple construction environments so I decided the cleanest way would be to create a method that does that.
Instead of a vanilla python function I've tried to use the `AddMethod` in the construction environment object since it seems to be the way of doing such things in `scons`.

However, it appears that methods of construction environments are unable to modify this environment.

Here's an example where I tested a few ways of changing a variable in a construction environment:

```py
env1 = Environment(VAR='foo')
def changeVal(env, newval):
    env['VAL'] = newval
env1.AddMethod(changeVal, 'ChangeVal')
env2 = env1.Clone(VAR='bar')
env3 = env2.Clone()
env3['VAR'] = 'baz'
env4 = env3.Clone()
env4.ChangeVal('qux')
print(env1['VAR'], env2['VAR'], env3['VAR'], env4['VAR'])
```

The result is `foo bar baz baz` while I would expect `foo bar baz qux`.
Why is that?

Comment: It was just a typo. The question should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you have a typo in your example:

```
env1 = Environment(VAR='foo')
def changeVal(env, newval):
    env['VAL'] = newval
env1.AddMethod(changeVal, 'ChangeVal')
env2 = env1.Clone(VAR='bar')
env3 = env2.Clone()
env3['VAR'] = 'baz'
env4 = env3.Clone()
env4.ChangeVal('qux')
print(env1['VAR'], env2['VAR'], env3['VAR'], env4['VAR'])
```

Specifically

```
def changeVal(env, newval):
    env['VAR'] = newval
    #.   ^^^--- You have VAL here, but check for VAR later.
```

Comment: Oh jeez, now it works. Well, I have to take another look at the real build script. I doubt I made the same mistake there because I haven't reuse any of that code to make the example but maybe it's something similar.

Comment: Consider bringing your issue to the SCons projects discord server, users mailing list, or our IRC channel

Comment: It turned out to be some kind of typo in the original code too. After some refactoring it started to work.

Comment: I'd suggest deleting this whole question then, so other's won't waste time looking at it in search of a solution to their issues?

Comment: Well, I've tried. "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center."

Comment: Oh.. that's a bummer.